# how to increase ecpm in any ad network?

Tags: android, admob, ironsource

One year ago I had uploaded one app on the play store and that had good ecpm. after a few months my app was rejected. after that, I make the same app again but change the project and copy that app code in the new project after uploading, my ecpm is down what is the reason? Please help me to find out the solution.

is ecpm depend on the app code?